# React / Redux - setting initial state with useRouteMatch

Tags: reactjs, redux, routes, react-router

Im using functional approach in my react project and im having an `<App>` component, `<List>` component and `<Item>` component (hierarchical). My redux **store** has `items` and `date` *state*.

`<List>` has a `items` and `date` prop and is iterating over those `items` inside the render part based on the `date` *state* from the *store*:

```
(List component. Before my 'try' and using hardcoded initial store `date` state)
    useEffect(()=>{
      dispatch(getItems(date)); (async () gets items from api with thunk > reducer > updates store state)
    }, [])
```

What im trying is to set initial `date` *state* with `useRouteMatch` to (for ex) `'19-3-2021'` when user enters `localhost:port/test`. But, if user enters following url: `localhost:port/test/25-3-2021` i want to get the date-looking-like string out of url and update my `date` *state* in the *store*. Basically trying for list to update its items every time date changes.

Note: I do not have any `<Link>`s leading to each and every list/date. So what i tried to do is using `useRouteMatch` hook. I tried something but i'm not sure if im having the right approach since im new to react.

**Index()**

```
<Router>
      <Switch>
            <Route path='/test'>
                <App />
            </Route>
      </Switch>
</Router>
```

**App()**

```
let match = useRouteMatch('/test/:para')
return (
   <div>
       <List match={match} />
    </div>
```

**List({ dispatch, items, date, match })**

```
let target = match.path;
let dateFromUrl = match.url.split('/')[2];

useEffect(() =>{
     if(target === '/ts/:para'){
            dispatch({type: UPDATE_DATE, payload: {dateFromUrl} })
      }else{
            let dateFromUrl = '19-3-2021'
            dispatch({type: UPDATE_DATE, payload: {dateFromUrl} })
      }
    
       dispatch(getItems(date)); 
}, [])
```

This is what i tried, not sure is this bad approach. PLUS, my `getItems(date)` is executed before my  `dispatch(UPDATE_DATE)` finishes updating the `date` state in the store and im not sure how to avoid that using some kind of async functionality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So a few things:

If you have the date in the url, you do not need to set it into the redux store. Just treat the url as a kind of client state and use this.

To get the date try the useParams hook:

```
List({ dispatch, items}) {
    const { date = '19-3-2021' } = useParams(); // This will set a fallback, if no date is set
}
```

And map it with

```
index({ dispatch, items}) {
  <Router>
      <Switch>
            <Route path='/test/:date' children={<App/>} />
            <Route path='/test/' children={<App/>} />
      </Switch>
</Router>
}
```

and dispatch like this now:

```
useEffect(()=>{
      dispatch(getItems(date));
    }, [date]) // This will now be executed for every date change as well
```

Comment: Testing it out. However, i need to update `date` state either way, since in my header component above the list im displaying the `date` from store with `useEffect -> setDisplayDate(date), [date]`. Can i just add another `useEffect` in `List` component which does `dispatch(UPDATE_DATE)` and have it with empty dependancy array?

Comment: Why would you do an empty dependcy array? Why not dateFromUrl in it?